# Why are my php crud operations working in localhost, but not server?

Tags: php, server, localhost

I have a create function that works fine on localhost, but doesn't work on my server. What I mean is nothing gets stored in the database, whereas it does on localhost. I use winhost, by the way. Here's the code:

```
public function create ($title, $content, $date, $price){      

$db = Dbclass::getDB();
$query = "INSERT INTO upcoming_albums (albums_title, albums_content, albums_date, albums_price, albums_img_path)
         VALUES (:title, :content, :date, :price, :path)";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$statement->bindParam(':content', $content);
$statement->bindParam(':date', $date);
$statement->bindParam(':price', $price, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
$statement->bindValue(':path', $this->target_path, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$statement->execute();

}
```

Here's my form:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form_c">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title"/>
        <label for="content">Content:</label>
            <textarea name="content" id="content"></textarea>
        <label for="date">Release Date (RRRR-MM-DD):</label>
            <input type="text" name="date" id="date"/>
        <label for="price">Price:</label>
            <input type="text" name="price" id="price"/>
        <label for="album_img">Price:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="album_img"/>
            <span>
                <?php     
                    if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
                        $upcoming_album->uploadImg();  
                    }
                ?>
            </span>
        <button type="submit" name="btn_submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and here's the code in the same file as the form that sets the create method:

```
<?php
require_once "../../controllers/admin/Album.php";
$upcoming_album = new Album;
if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
    $upcoming_album->setFile();
    $upcoming_album->create($_POST['title'],$_POST['content'],$_POST['date'],$_POST['price']);
}
$albums = $upcoming_album->read();
?>
```

The update method also does not work. However, the delete method works like a charm. CRUD operations work in localhost just fine.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Start by implementing some basic error control/error handling for your database queries – right now you are _ignoring_ any errors that might have occurred.

Comment: @abracadaver I've tried putting this in multiple spots and nothing happened. Where should I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Okies!. But in your view PHP crud works fine in local server but not server. The problem may be some issues like:-

1. You are using PDO's for inserting values in db (i.e) you enabled extensions on your localhost. so it works fine. but it may not enabled in server. so please try to enable in your PHP Configuration.
2. Or you may check this line., $db = Dbclass::getDB(); 
   if the db is active or not by

   echo ''; print_r($db); exit;

Comment: 1. I have no clue how to modify my php config on winhost. The weird thing is crud operations were working before on my server.
2. I tried this, and now I get a blank page saying "PDO Object ( )" with no option to expand it

Comment: 1. Check your database connection first. 2. check pdo by if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
echo 'PDO unavailable';
}

Comment: I tried this and got no message. Crud is working on another feature of mine. I'm able to store email addresses. I have a feeling it might be some silly coding error I didn't catch...but I copied everything over.

Comment: So I realize a file I renamed earlier today is still existing. I basically copied crud.php into album.php and referred to album.php. Now when I try deleting crud.php, it doesn`t even work in localhost...trying to find the connection to crud but can`t find anyway yet. Hopefully I`m just missing something.

Comment: So, as expected it was a really silly error. I was not filling out all the information in the form, and my table was requiring no nulls. Strange how this would happen, though, as I copied the exact SQL from my localhost, and I can enter nulls there....